# Spring Boot 1.2.8 with Spring cloud

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud

I have a need to use Spring Boot 1.2.8 due to a dependency, and with that Spring cloud Brixton versions are not working since it is looking for an Enum called Mode under class called Banner. I read that Angel series works well with 1.2.8, but unfortunately that is not available in the spring cloud repository https://repo.spring.io/milestone. Is there a way to get Angel.SR series which supports boot 1.2.8? Or any other suggestion?

Thanks much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only the *Angel* version of Spring Cloud  works with Spring Boot 1.2.x

Comment: Is there any way to get angel? I need spring boot 1.2.8 for a  project. But when tried to access from repository it seems 1./.8 is unavailable. One more question, I hope any Anger.sr version works with Spring boot 1.2.8, is that true?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve the issue i was facing. The issue was that, i was not able to use Spring cloud Eureka with Spring boot 1.2.8. I had a need to use this version due to a dependency. So I was able to resolve using below dependency.

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-netflix</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.5.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

---

```
   <repositories>
<repository>
        <id>spring-milestones</id>
        <name>Spring Milestones</name>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
</repository>
```

---

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka-server</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

```
Thank you very much for the help.. And appreciated.
```